# Hydrolysis of one mole of peroxydisulphuric acid with one mol. of water produces?

Tags: hydrolysis

I am having trouble in this question:

> [image: Structure of H₂S₂O₈]
> Hydrolysis of one mole of ***peroxy disulphuric*** acid with one mole of water produces :
>
> - a)two moles of sulphuric acid only
> - b)two moles of peroxymonosulphuric acid
> - c)one mole of sulphuric acid and one mole of peroxy monosulphuric acid
> - d)one mole of sulphuric acid, one mole of peroxymonosulphuric acid and one mole of hydrogen peroxide

when hydrolyzing ***H₂S₂O₈*** cleaving the S-OH linkage and S=O is of no use since it returns the same compound and peroxide linkage is non-polar hence can't be cleaved. So only ***S-O linkage*** should be cleaved that would result in the formation of ***1 mole of H₂O₂*** and ***2 moles of H₂SO₄***. But that doesn't match to any of the options. Can someone please explain me how to solve it?

Comment: The problem specifies a 1:1 ratio of peroxy disulfuric acid to water. So what do you get if you cleave one S-O linkage?

Answer (score -2):

Without speaking of mechanism, here is an explanation valid for the average high school students, not specially inclined to chemistry. Suppose the bond $\ce{O-O}$ is broken, producing two identical radicals $\ce{HSO4·}$. Suppose one mole of $\ce{H2O}$ is also broken into $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{OH}$. Then, $\ce{H}$ gets attached to the first radical, and $\ce{OH}$ to the second. It produces one mole sulfuric acid and one mole peroxymonosulfuric acid.